Actions moveToElement() is not moving to the element's center point
I have a table and when I try to scroll through the columns from right to left (i.e from last column to first column) using Actions.MoveToElement() method, the action performed, but the element is still behind the table width. The element is not completely in the viewport of the table. So when I try to click it says element is intercepted with another element and not able to click on it.
Code: Tried both Javascript and actions method and same thing happens.
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='tableId']/thead/tr/th[@style and @aria-label='trade-data-header-row-0']"));

import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;     
public void scrollToElement(WebElement element) {
//        ((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
        actions = new Actions(getDriver());
        waitForDOMToBeLoaded();
        actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
        waitForDOMToBeLoaded();
    }

Click Element method
 public void clickElement(WebElement element) {
        waitForDOMToBeLoaded();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
        element.click();
        waitForDOMToBeLoaded();
    }

If you observe the element HTS code column in original code is not completely in viewport during the execution. But when I check the visibility in viewport using this code after scrolling to the element, I am getting true. And if I try to click then I get the error as below. I am totally lost in the clouds.
public Boolean isVisibleInViewport(WebElement element) {

        return (Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript(
                "var elem = arguments[0],                 " +
                        "  box = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),    " +
                        "  cx = box.left + box.width / 2,         " +
                        "  cy = box.top + box.height / 2,         " +
                        "  e = document.elementFromPoint(cx, cy); " +
                        "for (; e; e = e.parentElement) {         " +
                        "  if (e === elem)                        " +
                        "    return true;                         " +
                        "}                                        " +
                        "return false;                            "
                , element);
    }

Screenshot during execution
Screenshot during execution
Original screen
full screen
Screenshot when scroll is not used
when scroll is not used
Error message:
 org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <button class="MuiButtonBase-root-378 MuiButton-root-351 MuiButton-text-353 jss665" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="sort-button-HTS Code-sort-by-desc">...</button> is not clickable at point (691, 152). Other element would receive the click: <th class="MuiTableCell-root-703 MuiTableCell-head-704 jss654 jss655 MuiTableCell-sizeSmall-707" scope="col" aria-label="table-checkbox">...</th>
  (Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.69)
Build info: version: '4.19.1', revision: 'abe0ee07dc'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.8'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$ByteBuddy$KCI95tvJ$ByteBuddy$PGBjE0aS
Command: [c3c9243fc7a1fdf218a46dc2561d0c93, clickElement {id=f.257F1F7CBD62B574E128FB297BA14BE4.d.ADEA7719F7D12F893130A70880BC813C.e.224}]

Element html


<table class="MuiTable-root-744" id="discrepancyTable" aria-label="discrepancy-table" style="max-width: 1635px;">
   <thead class="MuiTableHead-root-746 jss707" aria-label="discrepancy-head">
      <tr class="MuiTableRow-root-747 MuiTableRow-head-749" style="display: table;">
         <th class="MuiTableCell-root-751 MuiTableCell-head-752 jss702 jss703 MuiTableCell-sizeSmall-755" scope="col" aria-label="table-checkbox">
            <span class="MuiButtonBase-root-378 MuiIconButton-root-456 jss491 MuiCheckbox-root-612 MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary-614 MuiIconButton-colorPrimary-460" aria-disabled="false" title="selectTradeRows" aria-label="discrepancy-rows-all-check">
               <span class="MuiIconButton-label-463">
                  <input class="jss494" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" aria-label="data-header-all-check" value="">
                  <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-324" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                     <path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
               <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-628"></span>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="MuiTableCell-root-751 MuiTableCell-head-752 jss711 MuiTableCell-sizeSmall-755" scope="col" aria-label="trade-data-header-row-0" style="min-width: 230px;">
            <button class="MuiButtonBase-root-378 MuiButton-root-351 MuiButton-text-353 jss713" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="sort-button-HTS Code-sort-by-desc">
               <span class="MuiButton-label-352">
                  <span class="jss714">HTS Code</span>
                  <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-324" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                     <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </button>
         </th>
         <th class="MuiTableCell-root-751 MuiTableCell-head-752 jss710 MuiTableCell-sizeSmall-755" scope="col" aria-label="trade-data-header-row-1" style="min-width: 400px;">
            <button class="MuiButtonBase-root-378 MuiButton-root-351 MuiButton-text-353 jss712" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="sort-button-HTS Description">
               <span class="MuiButton-label-352">
                  <span class="jss715">HTS Description</span>
                  <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-324" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                     <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </button>
         </th>
         <th class="MuiTableCell-root-751 MuiTableCell-head-752 jss710 jss719 MuiTableCell-sizeSmall-755" scope="col" aria-label="trade-data-header-row-2" style="min-width: 230px;">
            <button class="MuiButtonBase-root-378 MuiButton-root-351 MuiButton-text-353 jss712" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="sort-button-NZ Value">
               <span class="MuiButton-label-352">
                  <span class="jss715">NZ Value</span>
                  <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-324" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                     <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </button>
         </th>
         <th class="MuiTableCell-root-751 MuiTableCell-head-752 jss710 jss719 MuiTableCell-sizeSmall-755" scope="col" aria-label="trade-data-header-row-3" style="min-width: 230px;">
            <button class="MuiButtonBase-root-378 MuiButton-root-351 MuiButton-text-353 jss712" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="sort-button-US Value">
               <span class="MuiButton-label-352">
                  <span class="jss715">US Value</span>
                  <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-324" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                     <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </button>
         </th>
         <th class="MuiTableCell-root-751 MuiTableCell-head-752 jss710 jss719 MuiTableCell-sizeSmall-755" scope="col" aria-label="trade-data-header-row-4" style="min-width: 230px;">
            <button class="MuiButtonBase-root-378 MuiButton-root-351 MuiButton-text-353 jss712" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="sort-button-Value Discrepancy">
               <span class="MuiButton-label-352">
                  <span class="jss715">Value Discrepancy</span>
                  <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-324" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                     <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </button>
         </th>
         <th class="MuiTableCell-root-751 MuiTableCell-head-752 jss710 MuiTableCell-sizeSmall-755" scope="col" aria-label="trade-data-header-row-5" style="min-width: 230px;">
            <button class="MuiButtonBase-root-378 MuiButton-root-351 MuiButton-text-353 jss712" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="sort-button-Value %">
               <span class="MuiButton-label-352">
                  <span class="jss715">Value %</span>
                  <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-324" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                     <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </button>
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>




you don't show the code that performs the click, but the click method should automatically scroll the element into view first... then click in the center.

Updated the code with click element. As you said it should scroll to that element when using click but it does not do that so I am using scroll to element. May be because it is with in the table element

that's really odd... don't think I've ever seen a  intercepting a click.  Make sure to remove all scrolling code/execute script stuff.  Might possibly be a click that happens during a scroll.  Maybe include the markup for the whole table header... maybe a  is grabbing input?

I tried as you mentioned. I removed the scroll method before clicking and this time it tried to scroll to the element, but still it is under the checkbox element. This time the column sort arrow button didn't even show up. Please check the SS in the original post where scroll is not used

can you include the code that finds/gets the button element?  The SS seems to show DOM before it appears.

updated the post with html code
